# how to implement the laravel pagination with auth()?

Tags: laravel, authentication, pagination

I want to limit my applicants list using pagination but i cant find a way to work it with auth(). is there a way for this to work?

Using the $users = User::paginate(5); works but i want to use the auth() for security reasons

already tried

```php
'applicants' => auth()->user()->applicants->paginate(20)
'applicants' => auth()->user()->paginate(20)->applicants
```

User.php

```php
// Model
public function applicants()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(Scholar::class,'owner_id');
    }
```

ApplicantController.php

```php
public function index()
    {

        // show all applicants
        return view('applicants/index', [
            'applicants' => auth()->user()->applicants //reutrn as collection if i dd()
        ]);
    }
```

foo.blade.php

```
{{ $applicants->links() }}
{{ $applicants->onEachSide(5)->links() }}
```

routes/web.php

```php
Route::resource('applicants', 'ApplicantController');
```

Answer (score 3):

Pagination works on a Query Builder or Eloquent instance.  You are attempting to paginate a Collection.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#basic-usage

**Without parentheses, this line returns a collection.**
At this point, the query has been sent and the database has returned the results.

```php
auth()->user()->applicants
```

**With parentheses, this line returns a query builder instance.**
At this point, the the query has not been sent to the database.

```php
auth()->user()->applicants()
```

Try updating your code to account for this small but important distinction.

```php
'applicants' => auth()->user()->applicants()->paginate(20)

// or some may prefer to explicitly wrap the user model
'applicants' => (auth()->user())->applicants()->paginate(20)
```

Comment: thats solves it but
this works to 
```php
'applicants' => auth()->user()->applicants()->paginate(20)
```
soo which one is better?

Comment: I tend to wrap items that return something specific (like a model) so there are no surprises later and I find it's easier to debug. But ultimately I was just typing on autopilot. In this case, you can write it however you like.